# More validation conditions

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 textboxes and I am trying to add validation hints when it doesn't meet specific conditions. The conditions are as follows:

```
Disable submit button and show hints until textbox1 <= textbox2 and textbox3 >= 15% of textbox2
```

Right now I can only figure out how to check a length or make it required with this:

```
public class AttributeValidationViewModel : AnnotationValidationViewModel
    {
        private string _FirstName;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "# of containers is required")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "textbox must have at least three characters")]


        public string FirstName
        {
            get => _FirstName;
            set => Set(ref _FirstName, value);
        }

        private string _LastName;
        [Required]
        public string LastName
        {
            get => _LastName;
            set => Set(ref _LastName, value);
        }

        public RelayCommand SubmitCommand { get; }

        public AttributeValidationViewModel()
        {
            SubmitCommand = new RelayCommand(OnSubmit, CanSubmit);
            //Doing this will cause the errors to show immediately
            ValidateModel();
        }

        private bool CanSubmit()
        {
            return !HasErrors;
        }

        private void OnSubmit()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Form Submittedffff");
        }
```

I would like to add something like

```
[CustomCondition(ErrorMessage = "textbox must have at least three characters")] (like line 5 of the code)
```

I just can't figure out how I would do it. I know how to disable the button until conditions are meant but I am trying give validation hints on the textboxes aswell.

Comment: Data annotations aren't the way to perform this kind of validation. What you should do is to implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data annotations aren't the way to perform this kind of validation that involves several properties at once.

What you should do is to implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface that was introduced in the .NET Framework 4.5. Please refer to [this TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx) for more information and example of how to implement it.